# Using JQuery to set CKEditor Value

Tags: jquery, ajax, ckeditor

I have a CKEditor textarea:

```
 <textarea cols="80" id="taBody" name="taBody" class="ckeditor" rows="10" runat="server"></textarea>
```

I have jQuery trying to set the value from the database:

```
$('#ContentPlaceHolder_taBody').val(substr[5]);
```

Don't worry about the substring I already tested that it is returning a string. For testing purposes I replaced the substring with 'test' and was receiving the same issue.

I know that the jquery surrounding this line doesn't affect it because the other textfields I'm trying to populate work. Just when it comes to the ckeditor.

Here is the script in whole:

```
function (obj) {
      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
          url: "ContentSections.aspx/GetContentDetails",
          data: '{"nodeID": "' + obj.attr('id') + '"}',
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (msg) {
             var str = msg.d;
             var substr = str.split('|||');

             $('#ContentPlaceHolder_hfContentSectionID').val(substr[0]);
             $('.txtAlias').val(substr[1]);
             $('.txtBrowserTitle').val(substr[2]);
             $('.txtMetaDescription').val(substr[3]);
             $('.txtMetaKeywords').val(substr[4]);
             $('#ContentPlaceHolder_taBody').val(substr[5]);
          }
     });
}
```

The issue was that nothing was being populated and no javascript errors were being shown.

I tried to read around but couldn't find anything that helped me. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to use CKEditor's API instead.

Specifically, [**http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#setData**](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#setData)

Comment: Solved my big problem great solution simshaun

Answer (score 11):

After reading this link http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#setData, following code work for me.

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData( '<p>This is the editor data.</p>' );
```

Comment: Note: Here 'editor1' is id of ckeditor textarea element. This also worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: Really good and helpful for me

Answer (score -1):

```
CKEDITOR.instances['IdOfCKEditorTextArea'].setData(value);
```

where value is like you want set html data