# CKEditor value set when html tags used

Tags: php, html, tags, ckeditor

[Using JQuery to set CKEditor Value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5519674/1347112)

My question is in regards to setting the value of a CKEditor. I am able to set the value when its simple text, but when the text has html tags in the value is unable to set.

Any clues?

Maybe there is a question similar already in existence.

Javascript:

```
 CKEDITOR.instances.contentTexto.setData( '<?php echo $var_myRow['contents']; ?>' );
```

Ok so I have figured out how to remove the html tags simply by this:

```
$var_contentString = $var_myRow['contents'];
$var_contents = strip_tags($var_contentString);
echo $var_contents;
```

And it works! Now when I send my variable to setData(''); like this it still shows nothing. Whats happeing here, can someone explain this a little?

Also when I check the pageSource the data seems to be coming through with the tags in the setData(); function. So its purely a display issue CKEditor has with html tags.

Comment: where do you get this string? javascript, php, static html, where?

Comment: Its a php string, question altered to include Javascript

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
CKEDITOR.instances.contentTexto.setData('<?php 
    echo str_replace(array("'"),array("\\\'"),$var_myRow['contents']);
?>');
```

Comment: Maybe the CKEditor is checking the structure of your HTML and if it's valid it'll set it as the content. Are they all saved from CKEditor? Do you modify the submitted HTML when saving?

Comment: They are all saved from CKEditor thats why they have the html tags contained in the string. What I want is to edit the data.

Comment: Ok, look at your database, and check if the cells which contain CKEditor data are escaped like "&gt;" instead of "<" and if it's escaped, then use `htmlspecialchars_decode($var_myRow['contents'])`

Comment: The cells contain the tags eg<p><strong>This text is bold</stong></p> and so forth, thanks for reply.